# Convert Rows to columns using 'Pivot' in SQL Server when columns are string data type

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I need to know whether 'pivot' in SQL Server can be used for converting rows to columns if there is no aggregate function to be used. I saw lot of examples with aggregate function only. My columns are string data type and I need to convert this row data to column data. This is why I wrote this question. I just did it with `case`. Can anyone help me......Thanks in advance.

Sample format

```
empid    wagecode    amount
  1      basic       1000
  1      TA           500
  1      DA           500
  2      Basic       1500
  2      TA           750
  2      DA           750
```

Desired output:

```
empid   basic    TA    DA
  1     1000     500   500
  2     1500     750   750
```

Comment: Note that you can always use, say, `MIN()` when you're pivoting without really aggregating.  As long as there's just one value, `MIN()` or `MAX()` will work just as well.  Also, it works for string values as described by your title (though contradicted by the body of your question!).

Comment: Check this https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/39000.sql-script-convert-rows-to-columns-using-dynamic-pivot-in-sql-server.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT empid , [Basic], [TA],[DA]
FROM (
SELECT empid, wage, amount
FROM yourtable) up
PIVOT (SUM(amount) FOR wage IN (basic, ta,da)) AS pvt
ORDER BY empid
GO
```

Comment: hi,
i have problem with---
SUM(amount) FOR wage IN (basic, ta,da) this part my codes are 1bas,1ot,1ta instead of basic,ta,da..

Comment: For wage in( your data)

Comment: when i replace it by 1bas i got the error 'Incorrect syntax near '1'.'

Comment: thanks AmmarR. it works....for me. the problem is just put the wage in square brackets and execute..thanks ..thanks a lot..

Comment: @Sivajith: So how does this help you with 80 rows per empid? I'd also compare performance of this solution vs mine

Comment: @gbn :in this case he use pivote to make rows to column and the values in rows that are taken by the query is just what we specified in the pivote table. so i think this is how it works..i also thank u for your contribution...i think this may also help u..thank u..

Answer (score 4):

Don't pivot if you always have 3 rows per empid. Just self join

```
SELECT
   t1.empid, 
   t1.amount AS basic,
   t2.amount AS TA,
   t3.amount AS DA
FROM
   MyTable t1
   JOIN
   MyTable t2 ON t1.empid = t2.empid
   JOIN
   MyTable t3 ON t1.empid = t3.empid
WHERE
   t1.wagecode = 'basic'
   AND
   t2.wagecode = 'TA'
   AND
   t3.wagecode = 'DA'
```

Also, welcome to the pitfalls of [EAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-attribute-value_model) designs

Comment: Thanks For the response..

But There is minmum of 80 rows per employee and arount 650 employees are entered...

Comment: your query is working only for single month data..and for emshaving more than one  month result is not getting....

Comment: So you need 80 self joins then to make 80 rows into 80 columns. Simple. Not sure what you mean by "single months data" either